# Yes, this is another ''str' object has no attribute 'write' issue

Tags: python

This is a what my code looks like

```
import re 

fileIN = str(open('instructions.txt', 'w+'))

contents = re.sub('a', 'x', fileIN)

fileIN.write(contents)
```

I want this program to replace the letter 'a' with the letter 'x' in the file 'instructions.txt', like this:

```
a
ab
abc
```

TO

```
x
xb
xbc
```

And then save the results in the same file. But, when I run it, I get the following error message:

```
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'write'
```

I'm sure it's a quick fix, but I just can't seem to find it.

Any help would be greatly appreciated! Let me know if I need to provide additional information.

(DISCLAIMER: Please excuse me for posting a really common question. I did look through many similar threads, but I can't glean any solutions. I just started learning python a week ago and I thought maybe I could try to write a tiny program to help me save some time at work. Sadly, this backfired as I have sunk WAAAY too much time trying to figure it out myself. )

(Edit: Thank you to all who commented and helped out. I thought my question was going to get downvoted to the depths of hell because I thought this question was so trivial. I feel really supported as a coding noob, and I'm glad I had this experience.)

Comment: What do you think `fileIN.write(contents)` does?

Comment: Is `fileIn` supposed to be a string or not? If yes, why do you expect it to have a `write()` attribute? If not, why are you assigning a string to it?

Comment: It's unrealted to the larger errors that the answers below are describing, but I suspect `"w+"` is not the file mode you want to use. Any `"w"` mode will truncate the file immediately, which makes trying to read its contents a bit useless. I suppose it could be useful if you're going to write and then later re-read some parts of the file, but that's not what you're doing. You probably want `"r+"`, which doesn't truncate, and lets you read and write in any order. You probably want to do your own truncating in between reading and writing though (in case the new contents are shorter than the old)

Comment: General note: avoid `f.read()` if you're working with very large files and only need to edit one line at a time. `f.read()` reads the whole file into memory before processing and it might freeze your PC if the file is about the same size as your available RAM. Go for the solutions that use something like `with open(filename, "r") as f: for line in f: # do something with the line` if possible

Comment: to be fair, `for line in f:` might also "freeze your PC" if the file doesn't contain a newline

Comment: @Eevee good point. If the file is essentially one line, e.g. json or binary, `for line in f:` wouldn't make a difference. In that case, reading chunks/bytes and using `f.seek()` might be better.

Comment: >jwodder, I think fileIN.write will put the contents of the variable 'contents' into the file associated with fileIN. 
>Goyo, fileIN is supposed to be a string. I'm not sure why I expect it to have a write() attribute. 
>Blckknght, Okay, that's a really good point. I will remember to open my files with r+, because it's a bit time consuming to open and close a file while working with it. 
>jDo, thanks, for the tip. I'll remember that when working with large files.
>Eevee, okay, I'll note that too, but I'm going to use f.seek() for my purposes!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No need to `import re` for this. The built-in `replace()` will do.

```
with open("instructions.txt", "r+") as f:
    data = f.read().replace("a","x")
    f.seek(0)
    f.write(data)
```

Comment: Hey, thanks for your answer. The solution worked perfectly!

Comment: But you need to add f.truncate() after f.seek(0) or otherwise random junk values are adding to the file

Answer (score 1):

You are opening a file:

```
open('instructions.txt', 'w+')
```

Then immediately turning it into a string *without first saving a reference to the file object*, and saving a reference to the *string contents* of the file:

```
fileIN = str(...)
```

Then you perform a substitution in this string:

```
contents = re.sub('a', 'x', fileIN)
```

And attempt to write to something.

```
fileIN.write(contents)
```

`fileIN` has, at no point in time, been a reference to a file object. It has only ever been a string, which cannot be written to. If you want to maintain access to the file object, save a reference to it instead of combining everything:

```
fileIN = open('instructions.txt', 'w+')

contents = fileIN.read()
contents = re.sub('a', 'x', contents)
```

You will then be able to write to the file object referenced by `fileIN`.

Comment: Thank you for writing out a detailed explanation. I tried it out, but it didn't quite work, but at least now I understand where I may have gone wrong. Although I already have my problem resolved with a different approach, I'm going to try to reach a solution based off of your explanation.

Answer (score 0):

Why did you use str?:

```
with open('file', 'r') as f:
    text = f.read()

with open('file', 'w') as f:
   f.write(re.sub('a', 'x', text))
```

Answer (score -1):

Make sure not to get file objects and strings mixed up:

```
import re
f = open('instructions.txt', 'w+')
contents = re.sub('a', 'x', f.read())
f.write(contents)
```

Answer (score -1):

It is telling you that there is no method write on a string object.  You need to call write on the file object.

```
fileIN = open('instructions.txt', 'w+')  
contents = fileIN.read()
fileIN.write(re.sub('a', 'x', contents))
```

Comment: I suspect this will simply delete the contents of the file